# How to substract the previous data with the data after in the same column continously

Tags: python

I have a column with thousand row and I want to subtract the data after with the previous data. But if I do it manually, it is not efficient, because my column has a large amount of data.

My goals is :

- in column one = a2-a1
- in column two = a3-a2

I want to know how to solve this with Python. I have browsing about this on Google but I not yet found it. could you help me please?

[image]

Comment: Please post sample data and the code you have tried so far, as well as the expected output

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WwJtm7Yj4shR4JHbbjl--zlU60sRhRLt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please visit this link

Comment: @Chris that picture is the formula that i want to know on python

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QsjmRRDtugZSee6tRw6ALwZwqWGRyL5g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: and on the link above is my real data that i have count on python

Answer (score 1):

Using Numpy

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data   = [2.092007, 1.755501, 1.309897]
>>> a      = np.array(data)
>>> result = a[1:] - a[:-1]
>>> result
array([-0.336506, -0.445604])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sample':[2.092007, 1.755501, 1.309897]})
df['final data'] = df['sample'].shift(-1) - df['sample']

df
```

Output

```
    sample      final data
0   2.092007    -0.336506
1   1.755501    -0.445604
2   1.309897    NaN
```